# Problems to run my CUDA program in ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

i have problems running my CUDA program, my script is the following:

#include <stdio.h>

__global __ void hi(){

printf("Hello from GPU");
}

int main(){

printf("Hello from CPU");

hi<<<1,1>>>();

return 0;
}

when i compile and run the program in ubuntu only display
Hello from CPU

can you help me to understand why is this happening please?

Comment: You should ask in a C forum, this is not a Linux/Ubuntu problem...

Answer (score 0):

Fix the space after __global and add the line:

```
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

before your return.
Then the comand

```
nvcc hello.cu -o hello
```

should produce a working hello executable if you have properly defined your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

---

The ldd output on hello is:

```
$ ldd hello
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcbe796000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f92f056f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f92f054c000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f92f0546000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f92f0365000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f92f034a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f92f0158000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f92f0610000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f92f0007000)
```

I do have the libpthread-stubs0-dev:amd64 package installed. I cut and pasted your source, made the two modifications mentioned, and it worked for me (both hello's on the same line).  Does nvidia-smi show the nvidia driver is in use?

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your help, i did it and still display Hello from CPU

Comment: When i put nvidia-smi everything goes good, i dont know what's happening because i use the same script on windows and run both hello's :(

Answer (score 0):

$ ldd hello

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc86398000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f465c128000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f465c105000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f465c0ff000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f465bf1e000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f465bf03000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f465bd11000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f465c1c1000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f465bbc0000)
```

Display this when i put ldd hello, i'm really new using this operating system so sorry i don't know what that's mean, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You should edit your original question to add information like this, and also edit the code you posed with the suggested corrections so I can do a cut and paste again to see if it works for me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help my solution was that I have to reinstall ubuntu. Now everything goes perfectly.